# I want to know why I am getting the "MasjidList.swift:13:43 Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation" for this class:

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am getting this error from my current swift class:

```
//
//  CSVDocument.swift
//  CSV-App
//
//  Created by Andres M Partridge-RIos on 2023-10-17.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class MasjidList {
    
    var masjidList: [MasjidDescription] = [MasjidDescription(id: ObjectIdentifier(.`self`), masjid_id: UUID(), masjid_webid: 1, masjid_name: "Masjid-E-Umer", user_id: 731, masjid_add_1: "79 Queens Road", masjid_local_area: "Walthamstow", masjid_larger_area: "London", masjid_post_code: "E17 8QR", masjid_telephone: "2085202658", masjid_country: "UK", latitude: 51.5784686402568, longitude: -0.0233741667985488, masjid_created: "2015-06-01 13:07:52", masjid_modified: "2020-09-21 12:29:15", status: true, country_code: "UK", full_country: "United Kingdom", TimeZone: "GMT", plusminusGMT: 0)]
    var masjidCount: Int = 0
    
    init() {
        //masjidList.append(<#MasjidDescription#>)
        masjidList.append(MasjidDescription(id: ObjectIdentifier(.`self`), masjid_id: UUID(), masjid_webid: 2, masjid_name: "Chingford Masjid,142", user_id: 92, masjid_add_1: "92 Chingford Mount Road", masjid_local_area: "Chingford", masjid_larger_area: "London", masjid_post_code: "E4 9AA", masjid_telephone: "020 8523 5826", masjid_country: "UK", latitude: 51.610806, longitude: -0.017989, masjid_created: "2015-06-03 18:55:22", masjid_modified: "2020-02-01 17:00:48", status: true, country_code: "UK", full_country: "United Kingdom", TimeZone: "GMT", plusminusGMT: 0))
        masjidList.append(MasjidDescription(id: ObjectIdentifier(.`self`), masjid_id: UUID(), masjid_webid: 5, masjid_name: "Lentrica Masjid", user_id: 303, masjid_add_1: "525 London Road", masjid_local_area: "Len Area", masjid_larger_area: "Len City", masjid_post_code: "CR7 6AR", masjid_telephone: "2082797895", masjid_country: "UK", latitude: 51.389457, longitude: -0.112676, masjid_created: "2014-09-27 07:55:58", masjid_modified: "2017-12-23 13:02:48", status: false, country_code: "UK", full_country: "United Kingdom", TimeZone: "GMT", plusminusGMT: 0))
    }
    
    func makeView () {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text(masjidList[0].masjid_name)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeViewList () {
        
    }
}

extension MasjidList: Hashable   {
    static func == (lhs: MasjidList, rhs: MasjidList) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine("id")
        hasher.combine("masjid_id")
        hasher.combine("masjid_name")
        hasher.combine("user_id")
        hasher.combine("masjid_add_1")
        hasher.combine("masjid_local_area")
        hasher.combine("masjid_larger_area")
        hasher.combine("masjid_post_code")
        hasher.combine("masjid_telephone")
        hasher.combine("masjid_country")
        hasher.combine("latitude")
        hasher.combine("longitude")
        hasher.combine("masjid_created")
        hasher.combine("masjid_modified")
        hasher.combine("status")
        hasher.combine("country_code")
        hasher.combine("full_country")
        hasher.combine("TimeZone")
        hasher.combine("plusminusGMT")
    }
}
```

I am trying to have this "Data structure" be available to my App, and the main point is to have the "Masjid Name" populate a picker in the App, and then the "latitude" and "longitude" for the selected Masjid be available to feed into my library for calculating muslim prayer times.

Comment: There is quite a bit going wrong here. `makeView()` would probably return something. It wouldn't have a `var body` property. And, your hasher will end up creating the same has value no matter what properties the item has. Probably a good opportunity to check out some Swift and SwiftUI tutorials to get a handle on the basics

Comment: do not use `var body: some View {...}` in your `class MasjidList`,
 it is only for use inside a `struct View`.
 Read the basics of SwiftUI and do some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to display list of masjids. In that scenario, you can just add a MasjidListView which will conform to View protocol.

```
struct MasjidListView: View {
    
    // array of masjids
    // var masjidList: [MasjidDescription] = [] 
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(masjidList[0].masjid_name)
        }
    }
}
```